# Retry method with 'fix' method

Tags: java, spring

Problem: Let's say I have a method A. When method A fails I want to go to method B (do something in it) and retry again method A once.

I suppose I could do it with extra method which accepts Runnable, do it in try and do it again in catch. But I am wondering if there is more proper(?) way of doing it in spring. I read spring-retry, but I didn't find what I am looking for (or maybe I missed something?).

Comment: That is exactly what try/catch blocks are meant for. How does your code look like?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.